# How do I make a message get edited when someone reacts with an emoji (discord.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'd like to create a help screen that you can scroll through by using reactions.

---

For example,

1. If you react with the information emoji, the bot's message gets edited to show the information page.
2. Right now, I can make the help message get sent when someone sends a message that starts with ';help', and I can make the bot react to the message.

**However, I can't get my bot to remove the user's reaction and I can't get it to edit my message.**

Here is the code. Thanks in advance for helping!

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.author !== null && message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.toString().startsWith(';help')) {
        const helpPi = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Help and commands')
        .setColor('0004ff')
        .setDescription('This is the help menu for available commands. Here is the table of contents:\n> 1 - Commands\n> 2 - More info.')
        const helpP1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Help and commands')
        .setColor('0004ff')
        .setDescription('Command A\nCommand B')
        const helpP2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Help and commands')
        .setColor('0004ff')
        .setDescription('More info.')
        message.channel.send(helpPi).then(sentMessage => {
            sentMessage.react('ℹ️')
            sentMessage.react('1️⃣')
            sentMessage.react('2️⃣')
            client.on('messageReactionAdd', reaction => {
                if (reaction == '1️⃣') {
                    sentMessage.edit(helpP1)
                }
                else if (reaction == '2️⃣') {
                    sentMessage.edit(helpP2)
                }
                else if (reaction == 'ℹ️') {
                    sentMessage.edit(helpPi)
                }
            })
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using `reactionCollector`s.

```js
let mainEmbed;
let penguinEmbed;
let sparklesEmbed;

const sentEmbed = await channel.send(mainEmbed)
await sentEmbed.react('')
await sentEmbed.react('')
await sentEmbed.react('✨')
// Adding await will guarantee that everything is in the right order, but it also slows down the operation

// This filter: only accepts the following emojis, and rejects the bot's own reactions
const filter = (reaction, user) => (['', '', '✨'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && !user.bot)
// Define a collector based on that filter for 60s
const collector = sentEmbed.createReactionCollector(filter, {
  time: 60000
}) // for 60s

// Launch it!
collector.on("collect", (reaction, user) => {
  switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
    case '':
      sentEmbed.edit(mainEmbed);
      break;
    case '':
      sentEmbed.edit(penguinEmbed);
      break;
    case '✨':
      sentEmbed.edit(sparklesEmbed);
      break;
  }
});

// When it ends, do something.
collector.on("end", (collected) => {

  sentEmbed.edit(
    sentEmbed.embeds[0].setFooter(`This embed is inactive`)
  );

  sentEmbed.reactions.removeAll(); // You can also just remove your bot's reactions, or anything else...
});
```

This is code I've written a long time ago. I didn't code a lot of basic stuff to keep the code as tiny as I could (the definition of the embeds, for example)

Comment: Whenever I react to my message, nothing happens. I don't get any errors, and I don't see anything out of the ordinary. My new code is here: https://repl.it/@DSASimon/Example#index.js
Also, how do I remove the reaction?
EDIT: I tried using `console.log()` to see if my code is getting that far. However, nothing happened in the console (if you are trying to find it on the link I provided, it's on line 28).

Comment: I think the error comes from these conditions in the filter you added `message.author !== null && message.author.bot`. First, the author of a message will never be null. Secondly, you just indicated that the filter will only accept the reaction... if the user's message is sent by a bot. You should replace this code with the new filter I edited in the message above. Also, I didn't write it but feel free to replace `switch` by `if`/`else`, it may be less confusing to debug.

Comment: I've tried fixing what you suggested, but now it stays on the screen I want it to for a second or two, and then it goes to the second page (helpP2). If you need to see my code, it's at https://repl.it/@DSASimon/Example#index.js .

Comment: I assume it's your `switch`. It looks like you forgot to add the `break`s at the end of each `case`. You can also just put `return` before the edit operation.

Comment: Ohhhhhh, okay, thanks! How do I remove the reaction? I've tried using reaction.remove() but that removes both the bot's and the user's reactions. I only want to remove the user's reaction.

Comment: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#removing-reactions